# How to manage session with restify-session module

Tags: node.js, session, restify

I'm trying to use "restify-session" module to manage session for my restify server.

For now , I didn't really have any luck with it.

Is there anyone here who can provide several code examples ?

Thanks !

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/mgesmundo/restify-session#usage

Comment: @robertklep thank for the answer , I've already seen this one , the thing is , I couldn't really understand from the simple example , how exactly I do manage sessions and it's ttl

Comment: There is always the source code: https://github.com/mgesmundo/restify-session/blob/master/lib/restify-session.js It's reasonably well commented.

Comment: Well commented but without any code examples , the framework it self is hardly used and last commit was 2 years ago ... probably I'll start to look after an alternative solution